# How can I add an index to a table using ClojureQL?

Tags: orm, clojure, clojureql

Using any clojure database/orm library, how can I create an index in a database?  I can't seem to find any relevant examples.  (I'm most interested in ClojureQL and clojure.java.jdbc, since I'm currently using those).

**EDIT**: OK, so I figured out a way to do this with clojure.java.jdbc:

```
(ns foo
  (:require [clojure.java [jdbc :as sql]]))

(sql/with-connection db
  (sql/do-commands
     "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS my_index ON some_table (a_column)" ))
```

---

But I'd really like to know how to do this in ClojureQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClojureQL is meant for generating the Data Manipulation part of SQL, CRUDing data, but not structure. To generate and execute the Data Definition side of SQL under Clojure, have a look at the [Lobos](https://github.com/budu/lobos) library, which is being made to compliment ClojureQL in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, ClojureQL doesn't have any support for manipulation of database schemas. It's pretty much geared only towards insertion and querying.